# Steps to determine if a relation of a set is reflexive,symmetric or transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am having problem understanding these concepts.

For example, let $A = \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

The definition I found says that
$x R y \iff 3 | (x-y)$.

How do I know if the relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive, symmetric or transitive?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you write down what these three things mean? That's the first step to understanding if they hold.

Answer (score 2):

This concernes the relation $R$. It is:

**Relexive** since: $\forall x \in A \quad x R x$ 
: $x-x=0=3.0$ then $3 | (x-x)$.

**Symetric** : If $x,y \in A$ then $3 | (x-y) \Rightarrow 3 |(y-x)$

Explanation: if $3 | (x-y)$ there existe $k \in \Bbb Z$ such that $x-y=3k$, then $y-x=3.(-k)$

**Transitive**: if $x,y,z \in A$ then $3 |(x-y) \, \text{and} \,  3 | (y-z) \Rightarrow 3| (x-y)+(y-z)=x-z $

Expl: $x-y= 3k, y-x=3\ell$ for $k,\ell \in \Bbb Z$ then : $x-z=(x-y)+(y-z)=3(k+\ell)$

Comment: What does the ∀ symbol mean? why is 0=3.0? Could you give me an example with a set? I've read these rules before but I would like to see it in practice so I can understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: The $\forall$ symbol means: for all element of $A$. We can verifie the rule for the elments of $A$ one by one, but we can in an other why represente any element of $A$ by $x$ an claculate $x-x$, this gives $0$ when we take any element of $A$. Since $3$ divide $0$ ($0=3 \times 0$)  we can say that $3$ divides $x-x$ for $x=2,3,...,7,8$, we write this as: $\forall x \in A \quad 3$ divides $x-x$.

Comment: Ok so therefore it is reflexive. It would not pointless but extra to write the 4-4 = 0 therefore 4|(x-x), and  5-5 = 0 therefore 5|(x-x) on so on  with the rest of the elements os set A right?

Comment: to make this more clear, could you provide me with a detailed example of the 3 properties regarding the relation R of the set {(2,3), (4,5), (6,3), (4,8)}? thank you!!!